# Is it even possible? Insert Frame/Iframe or (webview) from Click - Javascript/Jquery/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wanting a HTML page where a user can interact with it by adding frames to split the screen into halves, quarters, eighths etc... with the ability to then load a separate URL into each frame. My crude diagram below shows what I after (sort of)

Is this even possible using HTML/JavaScript?

Many thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible, but what do you need? Have you tried something?

Comment: Sure it is possible. iframes are elements that can be placed anywhere and their `src` can easily be set programmatically. Is it practical? perhaps not on that scale

Comment: Yeah I tried, I can build iframes/webviews and get the content to load, its the on-demand user based rightclick -> insert iframe part i have no idea about

Comment: add <iframe> to your page set it's display to none then play with javascript or jquery to change the value

Comment: For right-click listen for `contextmenu` event on document and do whatever UI you have in mind from there

Comment: In web applications you normally do not perform a "rightclick". Provide the user a button with a onClick event (javascript). Once the button is pressed, the given function will be executed. 
<button onClick="doSomething()">Run</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible, below is an example:

```html
<script>
var frame;
function addFrame() {
 frame = document.createElement('iframe');
  frame.height = "200px";
  frame.width = "200px";
  frame.setAttribute('id', 'superFrame');
  document.body.appendChild(frame);
}
function loadGoogle(){
 frame.setAttribute('src','https://example.com')
}
</script>
<button onClick="addFrame();">
Add Frame
</button>
<button onClick="loadGoogle();">
Load Google
</button>
```

If that dosen't run please see the fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/x6a0md5e/